# How can I specify fields to ignore in Hirb output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hirb

[This question](http://tagaholic.me/2009/03/13/hirb-irb-on-the-good-stuff.html) is helpful but not quite what I need.

I would like to provide a list of fields to ignore in a Hirb yaml configuration file. A blacklist, as opposed to a whitelist. This way, as my model changes from migrations, I wont have to keep adding fields.

I would like for something like this to work:

---

```
:output:
  User:
    :options:
      :ignore_fields:
        - password_digest
        - password_reset_token
```

Comment: Don't think that feature is available in `hirb` implementation